# Ethical concerns about OpenSTV binaries for download

Tags: discussion, election

I found that the binaries of the OpenSTV program for Windows and Mac are available on the [election](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election/1) page.  Thanks for allowing us to check the result from the available data.  However, on [their website](http://www.openstv.org/download), OpenSTV developers sell these files and ask others not to post them online or share them with others.  I do not know the license terms of this program, but I doubt that it is ethical to allow others to download these files.

(I do not know whether the files available on the election page are really the binaries of OpenSTV.  I have checked only their file names and have not looked at the content.)

*Update*: I noticed that these files are available only when a user is logged in.  I am not sure what this means.  As Suresh wrote in his answer, SE may have made some agreement with the developers of OpenSTV, which allows limited distribution to logged-in users.

Comment: it is a binary. I downloaded it and ran it.

Comment: @Suresh: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We made a large donation to the OpenSTV project to bring those with enough rep (> 150) a free download.  http://www.openstv.org/  Look on the right sidebar.

Those with < 150 rep will be directed to OpenSTV.org where they may purchase a download.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Also answered at the network level:

[Is it legal for Stack Overflow to redistribute OpenSTV binaries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78203/is-it-legal-for-stack-overflow-to-redistribute-openstv-binaries)

Comment: I was about to commend about how GPLv2 doesn't bind you to this. The link however explains my point. Since GPLv2 doesn't serve their purpose, I wonder why people in openSTV don't use a more appropriate license, e.g. Apache.

Comment: That question on Meta Stack Overflow focuses on legality, whereas this question focused on ethics.  Anyway [your answer there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78203/is-it-legal-for-stack-overflow-to-redistribute-openstv-binaries/78210#78210) along with Geoff’s answer here resolves my concern perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: @chazisop: It is maybe because they use a code distributed under GPL as part of their program.  Or maybe because they do not want to legally prohibit the users from sharing the software.  I can understand the desire of asking rather than legally forcing.

Answer (score 1):

You do seem to have a point, based on the statements at the OpenSTV site. I wonder if SE made some agreement with them or not. From their home page:

> Although OpenSTV is open-source
>   software, downloads are being sold for
>   $5 to pay for expenses, such as the
>   operation of this web site. The
>   downloads are licensed under the GPL,
>   but to ensure that OpenSTV continues
>   to be open source, please do not post
>   these files online or share with
>   others.